Why is transform: translate() not working?
I want to make an animation with same-centered circles (center overlaping), in the centre of the page, spinning at a speed defined from the user.
The positioning of the circles is what troubles me.
I thought these lines should be enough -in terms of positioning- : (in class .circle)
      position: absolute; /* So that they are overlapping */
      top: 50%; /* Moves the circle halfway down */
      left: 50%; /* Moves the circle halfway to the right */
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Centers the circle */

But it seems that transform: translate(-50%, -50%); is not working because the circles are positioned with their top-left pixel centered in the page, thus not sharing their center:
enter image description here
^The circles have their top left pixel centered, and not their center, in the center of the page
Here I add the whole code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Animated Spinning Circle</title>
  <style>
    :root {
      --spin-speed: 10s;
    }

    .circle {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 4px dashed black;
      animation: spin var(--spin-speed) linear infinite;
      position: absolute; /* So that they are overlapping */
      top: 50%; /* Moves the circle halfway down */
      left: 50%; /* Moves the circle halfway to the right */
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Centers the circle, supposedly */
    }

.circle:nth-child(2) { /* a second, smaller circle */
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }


    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div> 

  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="2" step="0.1" oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--spin-speed', this.value + 's')">
</body>
</html>


I checked a similar question but -webkit-transform() didn't do anything.
I'd really appreciate any help

You are overwriting one transform with another.
